# Unable to push from Visual Studio 2013 (works in git bash), libgit2 Category = Net (Error)

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, git-bash

so i just set up a project at work with Visual Studio and also added GitLab (with git bash) into it. Everything works fine for me on git bash but i am not able to push through Visual Studio (2013).

If I push with git bash it works fine but if try out the integrated git (in Team Explorer) from Visual Studio I get the following error message: `An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error)`

My project is just a Hello World C# console application.
Here some screenshots of my git settings and the error message: 
**Error message:** 
[image]

**Git settings:** 
[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you push it via git bash? And if there are any log generated by Visual Studio about this git operation?

Comment: Yes it works fine via git bash. Where can i see the logfile?

Answer (score 2):

Git changed their api a few months back and this broke a lot of built in integrations in various editors. You may need to upgrade the git plugin that you have (or install a different one of the one you have is no longer supported).

Comment: Thanks! Seems like it works on VS 2017 and i guess they won't change it for VS 2013.